# linearly independent generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm self-studying Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and I am not understanding one step of the proof of 8.13 (Linearly independent generalized eigenvectors). It is the same step as the one that "yields" 1.4.65 in the proof of Lemma 1.4.63 [in this book](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/595chapter1.pdf), which also leaves it unexplained.

We are multiplying both sides of the equation $\sum a_i v_i = 0$, where each $v_i$ is a generalized eigenvector, by $(T-\lambda_j)^k\prod_{i \ne j} (T - \lambda_i)^n$, where each $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $v_i$, and somehow getting:

$a_j (T-\lambda_j)^k\prod_{i \ne j} (T - \lambda_i)^n v_j = 0$

(i.e., all terms of $\sum a_i v_i$ disappear except for the one contained $v_j$)

I understand that each $v_i$ is an element of $null(T-\lambda_i)^n$ and so its term would disappear if the operator were applied directly to the $v_i$, but only the final $(T-\lambda_i)^n$ applies directly to each $v_i$. Are these transformations commutative for some reason?

I'm likely missing something trivial here and would appreciate your insights. Thanks!

Comment: Of course they're commutative. They're polynomials in $T$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks!!

Comment: Note that if they weren't commutative the product notation wouldn't even make sense: you'd have to specify the order, not just $i\neq j$.

Comment: Their commutativity is described in theorem 5.20 in LADR.

Comment: One other way to see this, is that $G(\lambda_i,T)$ is invariant under $(T-\lambda I)~(\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{F})$, so $v \in G(\lambda_i,T) \Rightarrow (T-\lambda I)(v) \in G(\lambda_i,T)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to bring this question officially to an end, I will make my comment an answer: yes, of course these transformations are commutative, because they are polynomials in $T$.